# Python bin data in specified ranges

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, quantile

I have a 1 dimensional array that has salary information like so:

```
|wage    |
|75000   |
|125000  |
|130000  |
```

and so on. I used the qcut function to bin the data, but I want to use rounded out ranges so it looks more aesthetic.

Currently my code is as follows:

```
quant = pd.qcut(df['wage'], [0.1, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]).value_counts()
```

and that produces

```
(42500.0, 50000.0]         3285
(27882.399, 32500.0]       3158
(32500.0, 37500.0]         3000
(69926.75, 82500.0]        2988
(58878.5, 69926.75]        2922
(82500.0, 110000.0]        2914
(110000.0, 145600000.0]    2866
(37500.0, 42500.0]         2677
(50000.0, 58878.5]         2554
Name: wage, dtype: int64
```

I would like the following ranges:

```
(0, 30000]
(30000, 50000]
(50000, 70000]
(70000, 90000]
(90000, 110000]
(110000, 150000]
(150000, max wage]
```

any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.qcut` is for when you want to specify the *quantiles*. For what you want, I suspect you need `pd.cut`, for example:

```
edges = [0, 30000, 50000, 70000, 90000, 110000, 150000, df['wage'].max()]

pd.cut(df['wage'], edges)
```